# Why update my domain's name servers to match the host?

Tags: dns, domain, hosting, nameserver

I have a dedicated server with a static IP from "Company A" that I use to host my websites. All of the domains are registered and managed by "Company B".

All I've ever done is update the DNS records (A records, MX records) on Company B's control panel so that all web requests, ftp traffic, e-mails etc. are forwarded to my server's IP at Company A - this seems to work just fine.

I could update the name servers so that they all point to Company A, but what are the main reasons/benefits to me doing this? Is this really only necessary on shared hosting packages where adding DNS records may not be possible?

Comment: The advantage to to using company A's name servers is they can manage records that might need update.  Static IP's rarely change but they might.  Also mail requires spf and domain key records for sending, which again once set rarely change but might.  The downside to using company B for DNS is that if a records needs updating things are broken until you update it.  Having company B for registration tho is outstanding, because if A can't ever hold you hostage.

Answer (score 0):

Using DNS service of a web host has many benefits like;

1. You don't have to manage 2 logins/control panels, one is for Manage DNS records and another for manage hosting.
2. Sometimes you are required to make changes in DNS records. For instance, you want A record of your domain to get updated for SSL certificate. In such situations, your web host can easily do that for you.
3. Some registrar's control panel does not allow you to manage all the DNS records.